# Resources$NotFoundException. Не могу открыть PDF из /res/raw

Tags: java, android, pdf

Подскажите. Есть ресурс в *res/raw/template.pdf*
Pdf открывается, работает, но при попытке открыть из приложения:

```java
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.template);
```

получаю ошибку:

```java
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/template.pdf from drawable resource ID #0x7f0e0000
```

Пробовал открывать так (все равно получаю ту же ошибку):

```java
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(context.getResources().getIdentifier("template", "raw", context.getPackageName()));
```

Что делать?

Comment: а вы уверены, что относительно приложения, res правильно лежит?

Comment: @Komdosh Остальные файлы открываются нормально. И да, до этого этот же самый код работал, потом перестал работать, после переустановки студио, проект не менял